# Swipe to delete without confirmation on UITableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, delete-row

I have a tableview with realtime data using websocket. The Table view refresh the cell(or row) every two seconds.

I want to implement the feature swipe to delete (Without showing delete button) because every two seconds i call the reload rows that time trying to delete particular row the table view alignment collapsed. Can any one help on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the [UISwipeGestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiswipegesturerecognizer) to your `TableViewCell` to do it.

**For example**

```
let swipeToDeleteGesture = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(deleteCellWithoutConfirm(gesture:)))
swipeToDeleteGesture.direction = .left
your_cell.addGestureRecognizer(swipeToDeleteGesture)
```

and process the delete function

```
@objc func deleteCellWithoutConfirm(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    guard let cell = gesture.view as? UITableViewCell,
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell) else {
        return
    }
    // delete your data first, then reload tableView
    your_data.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    tableView.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: 0), with: UITableViewRowAnimation.fade)
}
```

Comment: @Quock Ngyen I will check and let u know

Answer (score -1):

**Swift 4**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle:   UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if (editingStyle == .delete) {
            data.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.beginUpdates()
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .middle)
            tableView.endUpdates()
        }
}
```

Comment: did u understand my question